# calculate and sum cells in Javascript

Tags: javascript, sum, calculator

Could you please help me to code this type of calculation in Javascript? It is super easy but i just started with javascript and dont know how to do it, plaese look through excel file, i want the same for my website, I have table built in html, and when i input number in "quantity" cell i want it to calculate as per excel file,

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/32912319/sum.xlsx

Thanks a lot in advance!

here's HTML:

```
<html>

<head>

</head>
<body>

<style type="text/css">

td {border:1px solid black;
            height: 30px;
            width: 50px;}</style>

<table>
  <tr><td>price</td><td>100</td><td>200</td></tr>
    <tr><td>quantity</td><td></td><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td>subtotal</td><td></td><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td>total</td><td></td><tr>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: please post the html here

Comment: <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>

</head>
<body>

<style type="text/css">

td {border:1px solid black;
            height: 30px;
            width: 50px;}</style>

<table>
  <tr><td>price</td><td>100</td><td>200</td></tr>
    <tr><td>quantity</td><td></td><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td>subtotal</td><td></td><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td>total</td><td></td><tr>










<script src="script.js" type="text/javascript"/></script>




</body>
</html>

Comment: Not in the comments, reedit your question to contain it

Comment: done, sorry im new here :)

Comment: You must set up IDs for every cell, then take their values with javascript

Comment: yes but i dont know what is the code for javascript :(